# Is a closed subspace of a $k$-space a $k$-space?

Tags: general-topology

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206792/what-is-a-k-space-what-is-a-compactly-generated-space) there are three different notions of a *$k$-space*.

> 1. In Kelley's *General Topology*, $X$ is a *k-space* if for $S \subseteq X$ not closed in $X$ there is a closed compact subspace $C \subseteq X$ such that $C \cap S$ is not closed in $X$.
> 2. According to [nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compactly+generated+topological+space), $X$ is a *k-space* if whenever $S \subseteq X$ is not closed in $X$, there exists a compact Hausdorff space $K$ and a map $f:K \to X$ such that the preimage of $S$ is not compact.
> 3. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactly_generated_space) declares that $X$ is a *k-space* (or a *compactly generated space*) provided that whenever $S \subseteq X$ is not closed in $X$, then there exists a compact subspace $C$ of $X$, such that the intersection of $C$ and $S$ is not compact.

According to these definitions, is a closed subspace of a $k$-space necessarily a $k$-space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, no matter which of the three definitions at your link is used. Suppose that $X$ is a $k$-space, and $Y$ is a closed subspace of $X$, and let $A\subseteq Y$; $A$ is closed in $Y$ iff $A$ is closed in $X$.

- Using the first definition at your link: If $A$ is closed in $Y$, then $A$ is closed in $X$, so $A\cap K$ is closed in $X$ for each compact $K\subseteq X$, and hence $A\cap K$ is closed in $Y$ for each compact $K\subseteq Y$. If $A$ is not closed in $Y$, then $A$ is not closed in $X$, so $A\cap K$ is not closed in $X$ for some compact $K\subseteq X$. Let $K_0=K\cap Y$. Then $K_0$ is compact, $A\cap K_0=A\cap K$ is not closed in $X$, and $K_0\subseteq Y$.
- Using the third definition at your link: If $A$ is closed in $Y$, then $A$ is closed in $X$, so $A\cap K$ is compact for each compact $K\subseteq X$, and hence $A\cap K$ is compact for each compact $K\subseteq Y$. If $A$ is not closed in $Y$, then $A$ is not closed in $X$, so $A\cap K$ is not compact for some compact $K\subseteq X$. Define $K_0=K\cap Y$. Then $K_0$ is compact, $A\cap K_0=A\cap K$ is not compact, and $K_0\subseteq Y$.
- Using the second definition at your link: Suppose that there are a compact Hausdorff space $K$ and a continuous $f:K\to Y$ such that $f^{-1}[A]$ is not compact. Clearly $f$ can be viewed as a continuous map from $K$ to $X$, so $A$ is not closed in $X$, and hence $A$ is not closed in $Y$. If on the other hand $A$ is not closed in $Y$, then $A$ is not closed in $X$, so there are a compact Hausdorff space $K$ and a continuous $f:K\to X$ such that $f^{-1}[A]$ is not compact. Let $K_0=f^{-1}[Y]$. Then $K_0$ is closed in $K$ and hence compact and Hausdorff, and $f\upharpoonright K_0$ is a continuous map from $K_0$ to $Y$, such that $(f\upharpoonright K_0)^{-1}[A]=f^{-1}[A]$ is not closed in $K_0$.

Comment: An open subspace of a k-space is also a k-space

Comment: @DanielWainfleet It is actually not always true that an open set in a k-space is a k-space.  See the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4640637).

Comment: @PatrickR . Thank you.......................