# A criteria for an open subset of a compactly generated space to be compactly generated

Tags: general-topology

Is the following statement true or false?

> An open subset $U$ of a compactly generated space $X$ is compactly generated if each point of $U$ has an open neighborhood in $X$ with closure contained in $U$.

---

**(Added 2/16/2023)** Summary of the answers:

The answer depends on which notion of "compactly generated" (CG) space is used.  There are multiple variants of the concept, as mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206792) for example, or in Stefan Hamcke's comment.

**Definition 1:** $X$ has the final topology with respect to the inclusions from all its compact subspaces.  This is the definition in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactly_generated_space).

**Definition 2:** $X$ has the final topology with respect to all continuous maps from arbitrary compact Hausdorff spaces.  This is the definition in [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/compactly+generated+topological+space) and is the one more commonly used in algebraic topology.

Eric Wofsey's answer: with Definition 1, the desired statement is true.  Also note as a consequence:

> (With definition 1)  In a CG regular space, all open subspaces are CG.

David Carchedi's answer: with Definition 2, all the open subsets of a CG space are CG.

Comment: Each open subspace of a Hausdorff compactly generated space is compactly generated. Are you interested in non-Hausdorff case?

Comment: By compactly generated, do you mean *A set is closed if it intersects every compact $K$ in a set closed in* $K$, or *A set $S$ is closed if $t^{-1}(S)$ is closed in $K$ for any continuous map $t$ from a compact Hausdorff space $K$ to* $X$ ? For Hausdorff spaces both definitions agree. The latter one is actually for so-called *$k$-spaces*, but some people use it for compactly generated spaces.

Comment: In $k$-spaces, every open subset is a $k$-space. You can find a proof in http://neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/courses/homotopy/cgwh.pdf. There are however compactly generated spaces which are not $k$-spaces, so this is maybe false for this class of spaces.

Answer (score 4):

ANY open subset of a compactly generated (possibly non-Hausdorff) space is compactly generated. Indeed, let $U$ be an open subset of a compactly generated space $X.$ Let $A$ be a subset of $U$ such that for any continuous map $f:K \to U$ from $K$ compact Hausdorff, $f^{-1}\left(A\right)$ is open in $K$. We want to show that $A$ is open in $U.$ But as $U$ is open in $X,$ this is iff $A$ is open in $X.$ So let $g:C \to X$ be a continuous map from a compact Hausdorff space. It suffices to show that $g^{-1}\left(A\right)$ is open in $C.$ Now, $g^{-1}\left(U\right)$ is an open neighborhood of $g^{-1}\left(A\right)$ in $C$ so it suffices to show that $g^{-1}\left(A\right)$ is open in $g^{-1}\left(U\right)$. But, as an open subspace of a compact Hausdorff space, $g^{-1}\left(U\right)$ is locally compact Hausdorff, and hence compactly generated. So it suffices to prove that for any map $h:D \to g^{-1}\left(U\right)$ with $D$ compact Hausdorff, $h^{-1}\left(g^{-1}\left(A\right)\right)$ is open in $D.$ But $$D \stackrel{h}{\to} g^{-1}\left(U\right) \stackrel{\tilde g}{\to} U$$ is a continuous map to $U$ from a compact Hausdorff space, where $\tilde g$ is the restriction of $g,$ so by assumption, $h^{-1}\left(\tilde g^{-1}\left(A\right)\right)$ is open in $D.$ But as $g^{-1}\left(U\right)$ contains $g^{-1}\left(A\right),$ this is the same as $h^{-1}\left(g^{-1}\left(A\right)\right),$ finishing the proof.

Comment: Note: this is assuming Definition 2 of compactly generated spaces (see the summary in the question).

Answer (score 1):

This is true.  Suppose $A\subseteq U$ is closed with respect to the compactly generated topology on $U$ and let $V=U\setminus A$.  We wish to show that $V$ is open in the subspace topology on $U$, or equivalently that $V$ is open in $X$.  Let $K\subseteq X$ be compact; it suffices to show that $V\cap K$ is open in $K$.  Fix a point $x\in V\cap K$ and let $W\subseteq X$ be an open neighborhood of $x$ whose closure is contained in $U$.  Then $L=\overline{W}\cap K$ is closed in $K$ and hence compact, and is contained in $U$.  Since $A$ is closed with respect to the compactly generated topology on $U$, $A\cap L$ is closed in $L$, and so $V\cap L$ is open in $L$.  Since $x\in V\cap L$ and $L$ contains a neighborhood of $x$ in $K$ (namely $W\cap K$), $V\cap L$ contains a neighborhood of $x$ in $K$, and hence so does $V\cap K$.  Since $x\in V\cap K$ was arbitrary, this means $V\cap K$ is open in $K$.

Comment: Note for readers' benefit: This is assuming Definition 1 of compactly generated spaces (see the summary in the question).  I added the summary as the OP is long gone from the site.