# About the definition of $k$-closed set (CG2)

Tags: general-topology, compactness

There are various incompatible definitions of $k$-space/compactly generated space in the literature, as explained [in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactly_generated_space) and many posts on this site.  But let's focus on [Definition 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactly_generated_space#Definition_2) from the wikipedia article, which is the one commonly used in algebraic topology.

A space $X$ is called **compactly generated (CG2)** if its topology is determined by continuous maps from arbitrary compact Hausdorff spaces.  In other words, it is a space such that a subset $A\subseteq X$ is closed if it is **$k$-closed** in the sense that $u^{-1}[A]$ is closed in $K$ for every compact Hausdorff space $K$ and every continuous map $u:K\to X$.

> Is that the same as requiring that the topology on $X$ be [coherent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_topology) with the family of images of compact Hausdorff spaces under continuous maps?

> And at the level of sets, given a topological space $X$, are these two conditions on a subset $A\subseteq X$ equivalent?
>
> - (1) $u^{-1}[A]$ is closed in $K$ for every compact Hausdorff space $K$ and every continuous map $u:K\to X$.
> - (2) $A\cap u[K]$ is closed in $u[K]$ for every compact Hausdorff space $K$ and every continuous map $u:K\to X$.

Clearly (2) implies (1).  Can you have (1) without (2)?

Comment: Might be good to clarify that "At the level of sets..." etc. is a rephrasing of the same question, not a separate question.

Comment: @MW Well, it's close but not an exact rephrasing.  If (1) and (2) were equivalent, then the two notions of $k$-closed would be equivalent for sets, and the corresponding notions of $k$-space would also be equivalent.  But one could imagine (1) and (2) are not equivalent for a specific set, however if we quantify over all subsets of $X$ it could still be the case that the two notions of $k$-space are equivalent.  As it turns out from your answer, the two notions are not equivalent.

Comment: Let $\tau_{\mathcal I}$ be the final topology for the family $\mathcal I$ of all inclusions $i\colon u[K]\to X$, where $K$ is compact Hausdorff and $u\colon K\to X$ is continuous.  Crucially (exercise:) ), $v\colon K\to X$ is continuous if and only if it is $\tau_{\mathcal I}$ continuous.  Thus once there is a single set $A$ where we have (1) and not (2), then $\tau_{\mathcal I}$ is coherent with images of compact Hausdorff spaces, but not final with respect to maps from compact Hausdorff spaces, so $(X,\tau_{\mathcal I})$ is the counterexample for the notions of $k$-space being equivalent.

Comment: To elaborate a bit more, if $S\subset X$ is not $\tau_I$ closed, then $S\cap u[K]$ is not closed in $u[K]$ for some $u[K]$.  Thus $(S\cap u[K])\cap u[K]$ is not closed in $u[K]$, so $S\cap u[K]$ is not $\tau_I$-closed.  Therefore, since such $u$ is also $\tau_I$-continuous as well (exercise, or maybe further comment), $\tau_I$ is always coherent with the continuous images of compact Hausdorffs.  But it will not be final with respect to these maps, since the set $A$ that satisfies 1 and not 2 will be closed in the final topology, but not $\tau_I$ closed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation that $(X,\tau_I)$ would be an example where the two notions of $k$-space are not equivalent, given that there is a set $A$ in the original space $(X,\tau)$ satisfying (1) and not (2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  [one point compactification of the Arens-Fort space](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000165) seems to be a counter-example.  It is [not $CG_2$](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000165/properties/P000141), but it is itself the image of a map from $\omega+1$, so certainly its topology is coherent with the images of maps from compact Hausdorff spaces, as these images include the space itself.

(To define such a map, simply let $x_n$ be any enumeration of the Arens-Fort space, and define $f(n)=x_n$, $f(\omega)=\infty$).

##### Remark.

To unwind this explicitly at the level of sets, if $Y$ is the Arens-Fort space and $X=Y^*$ its one-point compactification, we can see that the set $A=Y^*\backslash \{(0,0)\}$ is closed in the sense of (1), but not (2).  To see this, note that if $u\colon K\to Y^*$ is a map from compact Hausdorff $K$, then $u^{-1}(\{(0,0)\})$ and $u^{-1}(\{\infty\})$ are disjoint closed sets, so by normality there is a neighborhood $U$ of $u^{-1}(\{(0,0)\})$ with $\overline{U}\cap u^{-1}(\{\infty\})=\emptyset$, hence $u(\overline{U})$ is a compact subset of $Y$, and therefore finite, as $Y$ is anticompact.

In particular, $u(\overline{U})$ is discrete, so $u^{-1}(\{(0,0)\})$ is open in $\overline{U}$ (either it is the pre-image of an isolated point in $u(\overline{U})$, or it is empty), hence open in $U$, hence open in $K$ (since $U$ is open), so $Y^*\backslash \{(0,0)\}$ is closed in the sense of (1).  But since $Y^*$ is the image of a compact Hausdorff space, and  $(0,0)$ is not isolated in $Y^*$, $Y^*\backslash \{(0,0)\}$ is not closed in the sense of (2).

(This is all really just unpacking the argument from [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2167614/1210477))

Comment: Very nice.  More generally, if $X$ (Arens-Fort space in this case) is any anticompact $T_1$ non-discrete space, its usual one-point compactification $Y=X\cup\{\infty\}$ is not CG2, but is coherent with the images of maps from compact Hausdorff space.  Because the Fort topology on $Y$ (one-point compactification of a discrete space) is Hausdorff and is a finer topology.

Comment: Feel free to add an explicit example of set $A\subseteq X$ that is $k$-closed in the sense discussed but not in the sense of CG2.

Comment: For the comment above the above, I meant to say the Fort topology is compact Hausdorff ...

Comment: Thanks for the Remark.  One could add a sentence mentioning the trivial case when $u^{-1}(\{(0,0)\})=\emptyset$.  And I guess $X$ is the Arens-Fort space and $Z$ is meant to be $K$?

Comment: @PatrickR Oh yeah $Z$ was indeed meant to be $K$.  Also I guess using $X$ for the Fort-Space was pretty confusing for consistency with the original question's notation, so I changed it to $Y$ to hopefully clarify that $X=Y^*$, so $X$ and $A$ now align with how the question was asked.  I might be being slow but I'm not quite following what needs to be said about the trivial case when $u^{-1}(\{0,0\})=\emptyset$.  Is there a reason that needs to be treated differently?

Comment: I guess I see the issue, I talked about $(0,0)$ being isolated in $u(\overline{U})$, which isn’t always true.  I rephrased.